# Hazy beer with new braumeister

Tags: troubleshooting

I've just purchased a 20 litre braumeister and have done two batches with it so far.

Prior to the braumeister I used a 3 vessel RIMS. After fermentation had completed I'd transfer it to a secondary, cold crash, then filter it. The result was reasonably clear beer.

The two batches so far with the braumeister have used the same steps. I even added gelatin into the secondary.

The resulting beer has been the cloudiest I've ever seen. It's not chill haze because it's cloudy at any temperature.

I'm lost for a solution. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you filter this beer post ferment too?  Was it reasonably clear prior to bottling?

Comment: Are these beers the same recipe just different brew system?

Comment: Are you getting a good hot break with the braumeister? If you're not getting a good rolling boil, it's possible the proteins aren't floccing enough to drop out in the trub.

Comment: I did filter the beer post ferment, it was a different recipe, same yeast though. With the hood on the BM I get an extremely vigorous boil.

Comment: @Jason is the new recipe a high protien grist? Like having oats or wheat additions? What are the mash temp and recipe differences?

Comment: One of the recipes had 500 grams of flaked oats. One batch was mashed at 64 and the other was 68.

Comment: Out of curiosity where are you?  Are you significantly above sea level?  The boil will occur at a lower temp and not lead to a good hot break as a result. If that's the case then a longer boil is called for.

Answer (score 1):

**Nice brew system Gratz**
I have no doubt you're reaching good hot break temperatures. Since your system is electrical heat with temp control with a vented hood.

**Water to Grain Ratio**
If I had to guess I'd say your mash water grain ratio was really thick less than 1.25 quarts per pound. A thick mash will extract more proteins making it more cloudy. The flaked oats have big proteins that extract easily in almost any mash situation.

What can also help is removing the hot break foam before it falls back in. I use a flat fryer screen, to extract the break or push back in as needed.

Comment: Cheers for the advice. I think the water to grain ratio might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to taste the beer myself it seems like your problem is the hot and cold break.  You simple are not coagulating the proteins well enough.  The added oats in this new recipe has increased the problem.

To be sure this is what I'd try run the same recipe again but stop the process after mashing.  Run of into a new pot and boil it separately (or only a portion), achieve a great boil and a good chill.

Hopefully that will knock down your haziness.